# How to find package and link library without cmake in simple cpp file?

Tags: c++, cmake

file name: main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"boolector.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
Btor* btor=boolector_new();
cout<<"hello world";
boolector_delete(btor);
}
```

What if I don't want to make CMake project, just a C++ file and still wants to link library as in CMake?

I want equivalent to following (in CmakeLists.txt) in g++.

```
find_package(Boolector)
target_link_library(project_name Boolector::boolector)
```

Documentation can be found at [Text](https://github.com/Boolector/boolector).

```
/usr/local/bin/boolector 
/usr/local/include/boolector
/usr/local/include/boolector/boolector.h
/usr/local/include/boolector/btortypes.h
/usr/local/lib/libboolector.a
/usr/local/lib/libboolector.so
```

Result of locate boolector

```
/usr/local/lib/cmake/Boolector
/usr/local/lib/cmake/Boolector/BoolectorConfig.cmake
/usr/local/lib/cmake/Boolector/BoolectorConfigVersion.cmake
/usr/local/lib/cmake/Boolector/BoolectorTargets-release.cmake
/usr/local/lib/cmake/Boolector/BoolectorTargets.cmake
```

Result of locate Boolector

I am using CentOS.

Comment: There are command line options for linking libraries. See `-l` and `-L` options. Also `-I` option.

Comment: If you are trying to add details, please edit the question and add it there, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-l`, `-L` and `-I` options of `g++` like:

```
g++ -L /usr/local/lib/ -lboolector -I /usr/local/include/boolector main.cpp -o main
```

- `-l` option is for setting the name of the library to be linked
- `-L` option is for setting the path where the library to be linked has to be searched
- `-I` option is for setting the path where header files of the library are present

To run the executable, you need to make sure that the libraries are there in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
./main
```

Comment: ./main: error while loading shared libraries: libboolector.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @GourishSingla, please see my edited answer.